# Deploying javafx 2.2+ app with Webstart

Tags: java, javafx-2, java-web-start, jnlp

Trying to get this jnlp to work but it keeps saying noclassdef found

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.5+" xmlns:jfx="http://javafx.com" href="$$name" codebase="$$codebase">
    <information>
        <title>test</title>
        <vendor>test</vendor>
        <homepage href="../index.html" />
        <description>test</description>
        <icon href="images/icon.jpg" />
        <offline-allowed/>
        <shortcut online="true">
            <desktop/>
            <menu submenu="test Applications"/>
        </shortcut>
    </information>

    <icon href="images/icon.jpg" kind="default"/>

    <resources>
        <j2se version="1.7+" max-heap-size="128m" initial-heap-size="32m" />
        <jar href="tester.jar" version="1.0.6" main="true"/>
        <property name="jnlp.versionEnabled" value="true"/>
    </resources>

    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security>

    <application-desc height="600" width="800" main-class="com.javafx.main.NoJavaFXFallback" name="Tester"/>

    <jfx:javafx-desc main-class="tester.App" name="Tester"/>

    <update check="always" policy="always"/>
</jnlp>
```

But the java console opens up for just a second before crashing. If I remove the NoJavaFXFallback, (running java 7u25), it says noClassDeffound javafx/application/application

Does anyone have a working jnlp for intranet app that shouldn't attempt to auto download javafx?

Comment: As a last resort, you can include the jfxrt.jar in your resources: `<jar href="lib/jfxrt.jar"/>` and place the jar in a lib folder in your jnlp folder. There probably is a better way but I'm not sure how.

Comment: See also the [deployment section](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/jfxpub-deployment.htm) in the Java FX tutorial - you might find answers there.